# How to extract a value in a nested json source?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to get the temperature from a json source. It's nested and I can't figure out how to get a nested value from a json file or url
So here comes my code so far:

```
    #! /usr/bin/python
    import urllib2
    import json
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=metric')
   json_string = f.read()
   parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
   temp = parsed_json['list']
   print "Current temperature is: %s" % (temp)
   f.close()
```

Right now I can get all values at once but not just a particular value (temp in my case)
I prefer to get the value clean without  u'temp': if possible.

Comment: Excellent @b4hand
That solved my case nice and easy. I've actually struggling for hours with this :-)

Comment: If only there were some [objective way to show appreciation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`u'temp'` is how Python represents `unicode` objects which is what JSON strings get parsed into in Python. Is this what you're looking for?

```
print temp[0]['main']['temp']
```

I don't know the structure of the API you're calling, so this may be making quite a few assumptions, but it will get you the raw temperature.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting several values back. To list them all do:

```
import urllib2
import json

f = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=metric')
json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
for each in parsed_json['list']:
    country = each['sys']['country']
    temperature = each['main']['temp']
    print "Current Temperature in {} is {}".format(country, temperature)
```

**Output**

```
Current Temperature in CA is 11.73
Current Temperature in GB is 11.8
```